# Implement `Refresh Token` in `Angular`

Tags: angular, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, angular-oauth2-oidc

I'm working on this `Spring` Security [implementation](https://github.com/dzinot/spring-boot-2-oauth2-authorization-jwt) with `OAuth2` and `JWT`:

According to the author I can access resources using token this way:

> To access a resource use (you'll need a different application which
> has configured ResourceServer): `http localhost:8080/users 'Authorization: Bearer '$ACCESS_TOKEN`

About this step:

> To use the refresh token functionality: `http --form POST adminapp:password@localhost:9999/oauth/token grant_type=refresh_token refresh_token=$REFRESH_TOKEN`

It's not clear for me that when I have to refresh the token and how can I handle this part into my `Angular` app.

**Do I need to implement a timer which would refresh the token from time to time or is there another way to implement this functionality?**

Answer (score 0):

An Angular based solution would involve these steps:

- Implement SPA security in the browser
- Renew tokens silently via iframes
- Validate tokens in your API

You wouldn't usually implement the Authorization Server yourself - use a low cost cloud provider instead.

It is worth understanding [HTTP Messages](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/24/spa-and-api-final-http-messages/) - step 22 does token refresh.

For a real world approach to SPAs and APIs, see my [Visual Tutorial + Code Sample](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/24/basicspa-overview/). You could then adapt the code to Angular.

Comment: I checked the links but I'm concerned about using `Renew tokens silently via iframes` is there other better solutions?

Comment: Iframes are the standard for SPAs and there is nothing better. You use a security library and avoid writing the code yourself - here is [some sample code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.websample2/tree/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth).

Comment: Ok, I will try to implement this solution.